# Why do functions use -(void) and not -(nil) in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, user-defined-functions

In objective-C I often see functions that don't return anything declared as:

```
 - (void)myFunction {…
```

But why aren't functions declared using `nil`, like this

```
 - (nil)myFunction {…
```

Don't they both return "nothing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically in languages belonging (syntactically) to the C-like language family, **void** indicates that there is no type being returned from a function.

More precisely, just as variables have (or belong to) a given *type*, functions also have types. For example, a function that returns a int, it is an *int* type function, or a function whose type is *int*. Same if it returns something else.

If the function does not return anything - it returns nothing - what type does it belongs to? It has no type, and the *void* type represents such a thing.

I'm not versed in Objective C, but if I understand correctly, nil is an *typeless* ID (or an id of any type), almost like a built-in implementation of the [null pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

And *null* is a (void *) type, the later being a *typeless* pointer that can point to anything, just as it would in C and C++.

So a function that returns nil would imply that its type is an id of any type. Don't know if that even makes sense. So right then and there, `(nil)myFunction` is of a type completely different from `(void)myFunction` since the former has one type (any type?) whereas the later has no type at all.

Also, nil is a built-in constant. Returning nill is like saying that your function returns a specific number for instance (`(1)myFunction`). That wouldn't make any sense, would it?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I always thought "void" meant "nothing", just like "nil" or "null".  But I can see how I overlooked the fact that "nil" is a value, not a type.  It all makes sense now AHHHHHHH!!!!

Answer (score 6):

`void` is nothing. `nil` is something (0).

In other words, returning nil isn't the same as returning nothing.

Comment: ...and you can't use a value as a data type, so it's impossible to declare something a method as returning `nil`. In fact, `nil` itself is (conceptually at least) a value of type `id`, so in order to return `nil` from a method, the method's return type must be `id`, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Void is an object type. Void means there is no return value.
Nil is an object, not a type. It represents an empty value.